# Django app throwing a 404 error despite a proper HttpResponse sent form view

Tags: python, django, httpresponse, http-response-codes, django-errors

I have been making a Django app within an existing Django project. All I wanted to test is whether my newly built app sends the correct HttpResponse text object to my browser from the view I wrote in views.pay of my app. The urls have been properly configured and also has been included in the project. Also, the project has my app added to its installed apps.

My urls.py in the project has :

```
url(r'^loginapi/', include('loginapi.urls')),
```

My urls.py in the app has :

```
  urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', views.authenticateRemoteUser, name = 'loginAPIUrl'),
    )
```

My installed apps in the project settings.py files has :

```
INSTALLED_APPS += (
    'core',
    'people',
    'places',
    'media',
    #Just added loginapi app to test my HTTP post request
    'loginapi',
)
```

My View is as follows :

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def authenticateRemoteUser(request):
        return HttpResponse("hello world")
```

Additional Data ::

Middleware are as follows :

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

What I am getting on browser is as follows:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://www.example.com/loginapi/
```

(Can't post image without 10 reputations)

Note : www.example.com is used for local usage and has been added to my hosts for my server ip. So, not a problem.

Note2 : My app is deployed in AWS EC2 but I don't think it is the reason.

Note3 : Do not bother about my url as I intend to build a larger app once this step has been crossed.

Comment: What else is in your project urls.py?

Comment: On the 404 page, does it say: 'Django tried these URL patterns'? If so, please add the output to your question.

Comment: @Oli it is a commercial project and I am not supposed to display all of them. But can you please tell me how they may be related? I am using third party apps like userena. Does it effect? All i want is just a simple request and a simple response, as of now. Is middleware effecting my HttpResponse object? It should not be the case as with the same middleware installed I have tried in another clean project generating a httpresponse of this kind and it got generated properly unlike this one!

Comment: Also, do you think that not using a template is affecting it ?

Comment: @Alasdair No. It doesn't say anything. All I get is a 404 page. Very hard to debug despite the debug mode being set to True!

Comment: Try moving `url(r'^loginapi/', include('loginapi.urls')),` to the very top of the patterns in your root urls.py, to make sure it isn't being shadowed by something else.

Comment: @Alasdair wow!!! it worked! Thanks a ton. never realized that this could be the case. I now understand the difference between an experienced programmer and a novice :)

Comment: Glad it worked :) In newer versions of Django, the 404 page will tell you which view raised the 404, which makes the problem more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `url(r'^loginapi/', include('loginapi.urls')),` to the very top of the patterns in your root urls.py, to make sure it isn't being shadowed by something else.

As an example, consider the following urlpatterns:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', views.catch_all),
    url(r'^loginapi/', include('loginapi.urls'))
]
```

A request to `/loginapi/` will be matched by the regex `^'`, and handled by the `catch_all` view instead of the intended loginapi view. You can fix the problem by moving the catch_all url pattern below the other ones.

Comment: Just curious, what could be its security implications, if any?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The risk of adding a url pattern at the top is that it accidentally shadows existing urls that are handled by other url patterns. That's a bug, but it's not necessarily a security problem. In your case, `^loginapi/` is pretty specific so it seems unlikely that you'd shadow another url pattern accidentally. However, I don't know the contents of your url patterns, so it's up to you to check.

Comment: Of bringing in my URL to the TOP of the other URLs. Why would someone use some configuration to shadow other URLS as it happened in my case when mine was at the bottom?

Comment: I don't know the contents of your urls so I can't offer any suggestions. You'll have to ask the person who wrote it.

Comment: Ok thankyou. Actually the person who wrote it is no more in the vicinity and I am all by myself. But thanks for your help.

Comment: If you use Django's flatpages, for example, there is such a catchall functionality. Its url pattern, if you don't use a prefix sur as "pages/", must be placed at the end of the patterns list, as if the url isn't found in the flatpage's db, it will return a 404 without waitingfor the rest of the urls to match (see [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/flatpages/#using-the-urlconf) for more info).